# JMeter 4.0 | Distributed Testing | Threads | Dashboard Report | Active Threads Over Time

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0, distributed-testing

I have configured the script with below configuration for the distributed load testing. Now, when I executed the script. The dashboard report which was generated: **Active Threads Over Time** show x-axis "Number of Active Threads" to be 25 only. **But according to the distributed testing setup if load testing is to performed for 50 users than on the master machine the thread is to configured to be 25 to run 25 each on the slave machines**

Now, the problem here is why didn't **Active Threads Over Time** show x-axis "Number of Active Threads" to be 50 rather than 25.

- Master(My own machine)
- 2 slaves machines
- Thread: jp@gc - Stepping Thread Group
- Number of Threads: 25

So, to properly access the graph I would require to have **Active Threads Over Time** show x-axis "Number of Active Threads" to be 50 which included each slave machine active threads. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Active Threads Over Time Listener documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/):

> If you are doing distributed tests, you should name the thread groups like this in your test plan:
>
> ```
> ${__machineName()}_My Threadgroup name
> ```

So you need to use [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) and/or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions as the prefix or postfix for the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) labels so JMeter Listeners could distinguish the sample results coming from different remote slaves.

Check out [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) for more information on remote testing including some tips and tricks like running specific samplers on specific machines, configuring/disabling encryption of traffic between master and slaves, etc.